# Attaching a file with changing name

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing a VBA query which automatically sends an email when you press a button in word. I would also like it to attach a certain file. Problem is however the file it needs to attach has a name which has an element in it which changes (like report+weeknr, the date part changes)

But because I also include the weeknr into the subject of the mail (like "Subject: report+weeknr") i though I could automate the attaching of the document through create a variable which is a result from report + weeknr. It does not work however. Anybody an idea how i can get this working? See code below:

```
Sub Sendmessage()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim var1 As String
Dim sentto As Long

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


var1 = InputBox("Insert week")
'Line below is where it goes wrong. Var2 leads to C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\SENS referentenrapportage - week " & var1 & ".ppt

var2 = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\SENS referentenrapportage - week " & var1 & ".ppt"

    With OutMail
    .To = "marcvanderpeet@gmail.com; marc@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Report_" & var1
    .Body = "Text" 
    .Attachments.Add (var2)
    .Display
   End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: does it work if you put path+filename into var2 as string - not using var1 - for test purpose?

Comment: what exactly is the Problem you are running into? Have you got an error message or just no attachment?

Comment: @Max, yes it does. But I already solved it. Had to define var1 as long instead of string. Now it works. Thanks for your input anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Sendmessage()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim var1 As String
Dim sentto As Long

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


var1 = InputBox("Insert week")
'Line below is where it goes wrong. Var2 leads to C:\Documents and    Settings\aa471714\Desktop\SENS referentenrapportage - week " & var1 & ".ppt

var2 = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\SENS referentenrapportage - week " &  var1 & ".ppt"

With OutMail
.To = "marcvanderpeet@gmail.com; marc@gmail.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Report_" & var1
.Body = "Text" 
.Attachments.Add (var2)
.Display
End With

End Sub
```